# Are database client files platform specific?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, postgresql, open-source-gis, database

I'm just looking for some clarification on a question that came up with me this morning.  Are the DLL client files (libeay32.dll, libiconv-2.dll, libintl-8.dll, libpq.dll, and ssleay32.dll) platform specific?

ie - If I have QGIS and ArcDesktop installed on the same machine, can I take a copy of those DLL files from the QGIS installation and move it to the Arc \bin\ folder and then connect to a PostgreSQL database?  OR, do I need to have a specific set of the DLLs for each platform (QGIS/ArcDesktop)?

---

EDIT - For Clarification:

[This ESRI Help Article](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002p0000003q000000) says that in order to set up a connection between ArcGIS and a PostgreSQL database I need to download a set of DLL files from the ESRI Customer Care Portal and place them in the \bin\ folder of my current ArcGIS installation.

I noticed that I already have a set of these files that were installed with QGIS.  *Can I just use that copy (from QGIS) in place of the ones I would download from ESRI?*

Comment: do I need to have a specific set of the DLLs for each platform? YES as windows installers writes to the registry - ArcGIS would have no reference to libeay32.dll etc.

Comment: So, are the files specific to QGIS and ArcGIS?  Or is it just a matter of making a copy of the set in the ArcGIS folder so they are available to ESRI products as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the answer to this is: 'Yes'

I copied the DLLs from QGIS and ArcCatalog wouldn't let me build a connection to my database.  I did find the files in the PostgreSQL bin folder and copied those to the ArcGIS bin folder and I was able to connect them.